# Solspace Calendar: conditional for minutes?

Tags: solspace-calendar

I'm trying to find a way in Calendar for start times that are on the hour (e.g., 8:00pm) to output as "8pm" and for times that are not on the hour (e.g., 8:15pm) to output as "8:15pm". I'm not figuring out how to write the conditional to do that. Any ideas?

EDIT: Just to make this a little more clear, I want any times that are on the hour to just be the hour (8:00pm should render as 8pm) and any times that are not on the hour should have the hour and the minutes (8:25pm should render as 8:25pm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at the demo templates, as this problem was solved there. :)

You actually need to use a different time variable available to you:

```
{event_start_date format="%g"}
{if event_start_minute > 0}
   :{event_start_minute}{event_start_date format="%A"}
{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I was looking in the docs rather than the demos, but I'll check those out more.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to handle this like any other conditional using the `event_start_date` variable.

So if you wanted something that wasn't a specific hour, but for ANY time, you could do something like:

```
{if "{event_start_date format='%i'}" == "00"}
    {event_start_date format='%g:%i%A'}
{if:else}
    {event_start_date format='%g:15%A'}
{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It _looks_ like it should work, however the first line `{if "{event_start_date format='%i'}" == "00"}` isn't figuring it out when the time is 8:00pm. In other words, it's giving me the same format whether the time is 8:00 or 8:15.